# Using Terraform to add OpenStack Security Group to instance not managed by Terraform

Tags: openstack, terraform

I'm trying to add security groups and new rules to an instance by using Terraform. Note that this instance is not being managed by Terraform. The issue I run into is that when I apply it it creates a new instance.

My Terraform code is as follows:

```
resource "openstack_compute_secgroup_v2" "secgroup_1" {
  name = "my_secgroup"
  region = "${var.region}"
  description = "my security group"

  rule {
    from_port = 22
    to_port = 22
    ip_protocol = "tcp"
    cidr = "x.x.x.x/x"
  }

  rule {
    from_port = 80
    to_port = 80
    ip_protocol = "tcp"
    cidr = "x.x.x.x/x"
  }
}

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "myresource" {
  name = "<Name of MY Instance>"
  flavor_name = "m1.medium"
  region = "${var.region}"
  image_id = "<Image I.D of existing instance>"
  security_groups = ["${openstack_compute_secgroup_v2.secgroup_1.name}"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Terraform code is meant to be creating a new instance on your OpenStack cluster. To have Terraform manage a resource it must be included in its [state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/) file. When you create a resource with Terraform then Terraform will automatically put it inside the state file and then begin to manage that resource.

Since Terraform 0.7 many resources can now be [imported](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/) into the state file like this:

```
$ terraform import aws_instance.web i-12345678
```

If you had some Terraform code like this (from the [aws_instance documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html)):

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-west-2"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
  filter {
    name = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags {
        Name = "HelloWorld"
    }
}
```

And already had a pre-existing instance with an instance id of `i-12345678` then Terraform would have imported that instance and now running a plan of the above code should show no changes instead of creating the `web` instance.

Unfortunately it looks like OpenStack support isn't as mature as AWS and so (as of 0.7.7) there is not currently any support for importing OpenStack instance resources directly using the `import` command. However, the `import` command is simply making it easier to manipulate the state file without breaking things and so you can just edit the state file to include the resource.

Comment: thank you for the info. Hopefully they give out the import support for Open Stack as well.

Comment: There is some support for importing OpenStack resources just not yet for instances